# Stop a infinite loop in Pythonw (without console)

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, infinite-loop, pythonw

I have written a code in Python to open a website in infinite loop, also I made it to Pythonw (without console). I want to stop it without powering off my computer, is there any way to do it?

Comment: Kill the process in the task manager

Comment: If you are on windows you can kill the process using Task Manager. Ctrl+Alt+Escape on the keyboard will open the Tadk Manager, then find the python process, right click and press Stop/End/Terminate (not sure what the name is)

Answer (score 0):

From your script, you can use the sys module, 
for example with the

```
sys.exit()
```

command.
You could also use exponential back-off, by adding an increasing sleep-step within a try block, if you need to retry opening the URL.